# how to make random value constant in every running at python?

Tags: python, pandas, random

I want to make a random value, but in every running program, the random value always changes. can I have random value constantly? how the code?

Comment: Store it externally to Python in a file or database.

Comment: If it needs to be consistent, why not just hard-code the arbitrary "random" number? You could even create a generator go iterate through a tuple, depending on your exact need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize the code with the [seed value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed). That will depend on which library you use, but if you are using the built-in `random`, then you can set the seed as follows:

```py
import random
random.seed(100)

print(random.random())
```

If you run this code, you will see that it gives you the same random value each time.

Answer (score 2):

The random number generator in numpy allows for entering a seed:

```
import numpy as np
seed = 25
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
```

Then create a consistent stream of random numbers using the random() method:

```
rng.random()
```